# What's the interval that I need to transpose from C minor to E minor?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, transposition

Would this be a minor third of a major third? Sorry if this is a simple question, it's been a while since I studied music theory.

For an example, suppose there was an Fmaj chord within the C minor music piece. When this is transposed to E minor, does this chord become Amaj or Amin?

Comment: If it's been a while since you studied theory, a picture of the sheet music would give you more accurate answers.  How do you know the piece is in C minor, and not some other mode?

Comment: I was playing by ear with some guitar chords as a backbone so there's no sheets. The question was answered but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that they're both minors (they would be, you're transposing!) is a red herring.

The interval is between **C** and **E**, which is **M3** - a major third. Everything - chords and dots need to move up by 4 semitones.

In key C minor, F major is IV. Transposing to key E minor, IV is now A major. Majors transpose to majors, minors to minors, augs to augs, etc. - the transposition certainly won't affect the 'flavour' of the chord - only its name.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. Also I apologize, the website doesn't let me upvote you.

Comment: You will be able to once you reach a specific level of reputation, keep trying, I gave you a +1.